# How do I get SvelteKit and TypeORM to work together?

Tags: typeorm, sveltekit

I know that SvelteKit is still in beta and changing a lot, but I'd still like to ask about getting TypeORM to work with the SvelteKit dev server and production node server.

I made a [minimal repository](https://github.com/Glench/sveltekit-typeorm-test) with a basic SvelteKit project (using `npm init svelte@next`) and TypeORM (using installation instructions [here](https://typeorm.io/)).

When I try to do `npm run dev --` I get a warning that `import-metadata` isn't importing correctly:

```
reflect-metadata doesn't appear to be written in CJS, but also doesn't appear to be a valid ES module (i.e. it doesn't have "type": "module" or an .mjs extension for the entry point). Please contact the package author to fix.
```

Then I get an exception from TypeORM:

```
[vite] Error when evaluating SSR module /src/lib/User.ts:
ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for User#id is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported).If you are using JavaScript instead of TypeScript you must explicitly provide a column type.
```

I'm not sure why the reflect-metadata library doesn't seem to be importing correctly. I've tried both import "reflect-metadata" and import * as Reflect from 'reflect-metadata'; but got the same error. Heck, I even tried copying and pasting the JS library into hooks.ts and commenting out the imports, but the same reflect-metadata and TypeORM errors seem to happen.

Right now my assumption is that if the reflect-metadata library can be imported correctly then that would fix the TypeORM error, but I'm not sure. [Here's a relevant issue in the SvelteKit Github](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/798) and [here's a reddit thread I made without much help](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/s0nov1/getting_errors_with_typeorm_and_sveltekit_any/). I'm hoping that my issue can be solved without opening a new SvelteKit issue but I want to make sure that it's possible to use TypeORM with SvelteKit since it's the most starred JS ORM on Github.

If you have any ideas or solutions I'd love to hear them!

Answer (score 0):

Probably too late, but if someone else stumbles on this - typing the Column fixed the issue for me. ie. adding the `'text', {nullable:false}` part.

```
@Entity()
export default class User extends BaseEntity {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column('text', { nullable: false })
    email: string;
}
```